# how to get props in vue3 composition api

Tags: vuejs3

I try to write a container component "A" to layout a third-party component "Tree", in order to use A, I use "inheritAttrs" to get all props and event of "Tree":

```vue
<template>
    <Tree v-bind="$attrs" />
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  export default {
    inheritAttrs: true,
  };
</script>
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { Tree } from 'ant-design-vue';
  import { onMounted, PropType, toRef, unref, ref, toRefs } from 'vue';
  function A() {
      // this is not working
      console.log(props);
   }

</script>
```

how can I get some props atrributes inherit from "Tree" in function A?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## 'InheritAttrs'

Firstly, [inheritAttrs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance) does not mean *inheriting props*, `inheritAttrs` set to true means you inherit the **attributes** (not **props**) automatically and bind those attributes to the root node of the component.

###### What are 'Attributes'?

Some common ones are `class`, `style`, `id`, `disabled`, `required` and `minlength` attributes to name a few. Basically all native HTML attributes are addressed by `inheritAttrs`.

---

## How to access the `props` object inside `<script setup>`?

In the composition API, you need to explicitly [define](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html) the props in `<script setup>` to be able to use the `props` object.

In Single File Components (SFCs) using `<script setup>`, props can be declared using the defineProps() macro:

```html
<script setup>
   const props = defineProps(['foo'])

   console.log(props.foo)
</script>
```

...

---

## Read More: What if I have a `prop` with the same name as an `attribute`?

Let's set up an example. You define a prop named `disabled` in `MyComponent.vue`.

***MyComponent.vue***

```html
<template>
   <Tree v-bind="$attrs"/>
</template>
 
<script setup>
   const props =  defineProps({
      disabled: Boolean,
   })
       
   console.log(props.disabled); // this works
</script>
```

... and then add the component like this, passing in `disabled`. Note that `:disabled="true"` and just `disabled` mean the same thing in both cases - when props are defined or not.

***App.vue***

```html
<MyComponent disabled />
```

Since you defined the props using, `defineProps()` the `v-bind="$attrs"` will no longer be having `disabled` as an attribute in the `$attrs` object. This is just as the docs explain:

> Vue components require explicit props declaration **so that Vue knows what external props passed to the component should be treated as fallthrough attributes**...

In other words, if you don't define the `props`, they will be treated as `attributes`.

Comment: Thanks, now I know how to make this work: just re-decalared the attribute I need in my custom component

Answer (score 6):

You can define typesafe props with Typescript and Composition API (`<script setup lang="ts" />`) like:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  foo: { type: String, required: true },
  bar: Number
})

props.foo // string
props.bar // number | undefined
</script>
```

> However, it is usually more straightforward to define props with pure
> types via a generic type argument:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
interface Props {
  foo: string,
  bar?: number
}
const props = defineProps<Props>()

props.foo // string
props.bar // number | undefined
</script>
```

See [Docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props). If you want to set default values too. See [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features)

Answer (score 1):

You can use also following way:

```html
export default {  
...    
    props:["filterOptions"],
    setup(props, context) {      
     const optionsinProps = props.filterOptions;
    }  
...
 };
```