# How to pass props with Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

I'm trying to pass props with Pinia composition API, but not getting any data. I don't get any console log value at all.  What am I doing wrong ?

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ['user'],
  setup(props) {
    console.log('user', props);
    const user = props.user;
    return user;
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: The question is unclear. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The component isn't related to pinia. It's unclear whether you don't have any console output or a value is undefined or something else.

Comment: You should at least show us how you're using this component. What you have [works](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpdUMFOxCAQ/ZUJF9qk0sRjZU2MNw968Cge6krXJhQIDBtN0393oKZ19zTMvDdv3mNmD96Lc9KsYzIew+gRosbk75UdJ+8CwqOjarVFGIKbgIt2m+RFruzR2YiQog5wgBkG5zrgH33gsCgr21WWBKlBPXnTo6YOQO7SXd4+KJaLYtASLtuNzBp2cXM3Szz9XWx+6qFPBmHOyj44Hzt441mPvzd5VmJVBalXFkB27owWxp2qldusu/XdTtiiFUTk5g8NJBlsgctkoUMLvf5lvkysUPqg4XzzhZOhuE+vL88iYhjtaRx+qizUgE3GNHBbK3b9DcsvR3+VVA==).

Comment: By the way, you don't need to return `user` from `setup()`, it's already available to `<template>` from `props`. [Example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpdjzFrwzAQhf/KQ4ticG3oqMqB0q1DO3SsOripnBpkSUin0GL83yM5kOBMx7179+67mT1735ySZoLJeAijJ0RNye+VHSfvAuHF5Wq1JQzBTeBNe1XKIlf24GwkpKgDOswYnBPg333gWJSV7SU2B+aG9ORNTzp3gLxFi7LdKVaKYmjzXLZXM6vZ5uYNNvv034r5o4c+GcJckn1wPgp88pLHv+qirW8J7NZZhW6Pwu2Mbow7XtSm2Ctll6cN95ZakfRB4/TwS5PJyK8f729NpDDa4zj870pEDZuMqfFYKXb/ynIGG96B/Q==).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get props in vue3 composition api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71569344/how-to-get-props-in-vue3-composition-api)